# How to increment multiple variables in a loop?`

Tags: sql-server, while-loop

I am trying to execute a while loop but missing some syntax I guess.
I have a column with years ranging 1871 to 2010. I am trying to assign these years in a ranged value.. Like all years between 1871 to 18765 as '1' then 1876 to 1880 as '2' and s on.
I am unable to execute the loop correctly. please shed some light.

SQL Server Code: ( guess something is wrong when trying to increment @i,@year..)

```
DECLARE @i int = 0,
@year int = 1875,
@yearstart int = 1870

WHILE (@i < 30)
BEGIN
   UPDATE [train]
   SET [YearBuilt] = @i
   WHERE [YearBuilt]  between  @yearstart and  @year 

    SET @i = @i + 1
    SET @year = @year + 5
    SET @yearstart = @year + 6
END
```

Comment: What error you have?

Answer (score 2):

Add `;`  and why `@year + 6` instead of `+ 5` ?

```
DECLARE 

@i int = 0,
@year int = 1875,
@yearstart int = 1870

WHILE (@i < 30)
BEGIN
   update train 
   set YearBuilt =@i
   where YearBuilt  between  @yearstart and  @year;
   SET   @i = @i + 1;
   SET   @year = @year + 5;
   SET   @yearstart = @year + 5; 
END
```

Comment: hi! Juan. Your suggested edit did not solve my problem. I am still not able to normalize all my years in yearsbuilt column. Why is that? is the loop not executing well?

Comment: be more specific, what is the problem?

Comment: I got the answer. I just did a logical error. i forgot to add 'start' while making increment in $yearstart.(see my post) apart much thanks to correct my syntax for SET attribute @juan